# History with JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, audit-trail

I need to keep change of entities in a little bit tricky fashion. There is one HISTORY table for all entities with structure something like this
`TABLE`
`ATTR`
`VALUE`
`DATE`
`TYPE`(insert/update/delete)

As I am quite novice in JPA I don't realize how to achive this using JPA. Or it's better to use JDBC for this purpose?

UPD: JPA implementation is EclipseLink

Comment: Do you need to preserve state of your original object? I.e. do you need to know values of all fields at the moment of modification or you just need to log event?

Comment: I just need to log events. This history table will be used only in sql

Comment: The easiest way then would be to have a trigger in database to insert new automatically add log.
Another approach would be to use JPA events: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event

Comment: Which implementation are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: Trigger is not suitable because I also need to store user who made changes. And this info I have only in application, not in DB

Comment: I use EclipseLink. I've updated question

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107363/how-to-use-jpa-life-cycle-events-to-get-entity-data) gives you a hint, how you can use JPA events for this. Downside: you need to annotate all entities for this.

Answer (score 0):

JPA itself does not have a solution for this, so you have to use implementation specific solutions.

For your implementation, try [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History) and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657253/eclipselink-audit-history-track-changes).